# How to: Trigger social share button (click) event from another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook, twitter

My app has an invitation system, where users can customize their own invitation url (ex: http://www.app.com/i/jointhepartywithme), and I need to have my three social share buttons (fb, twitter, linkedin) take the customized url and share that. I'm also using customized (different, hand-coded) buttons for the social networks (fb, twitter, linkedin) because the default ones are hard to style and ugly. I can't get my custom-made button "click" event to trigger a click on the real buttons (which I've hidden cause they're ugly).

Is this a bad approach, should I just figure out how to customized the CSS for each of my social share buttons? I've tried this before, and I remember changing CSS on iframes is a huge PITA.

I've tried .on .live .delegate. Nothing seems to be able to trigger the social share buttons. Two of them are iframes, one is not. Any advice on how to approach this situation?

Here is my code demonstrating different approaches I've tried.

```
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){

    $('#invite_section').on('click', 'div.twitter', function(){
      alert("Twitter clicked.");
      $('#twitter-widget-0').contents().find("body").click();
    });

    $('#invite_section').on('click', 'div.facebook', function(){
      alert("Facebook clicked.");
      var stuff = $('div.fb-share-button').trigger('click');
    });

    $('#invite_section').on('click', 'div.linkedin', function(){
      alert("LinkedIn clicked.");
      $('span.IN-widget')[0].click();
    });

  });
```

Comment: Correct. That will not work. Just trigger the share dialog directly for Facebook. Don't click the button

Comment: OK So I will now embark on the adventure of figuring out how to trigger the dialog manually. Thanks!

Comment: You call FB.ui as explained in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: FB was easy. Thanks for pointing me to the right docs. The other two are really tough. Not sure how I can style them since one is in an frame, and the other has very strict CSS rules.

Comment: Most social networks allow to call their share functionality via a simple URL - so you don't have to hand any click events around, but can just use simple links (with target=_blank, and formatted to look like a button.) Take a look at the list here: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls

Comment: @CBroe Neat! Why do they have these other complicated methods in their docs... ? LOL THANK YOU

Comment: Well they of course _prefer_ that you embed their own social sharing scripts/SDKs - that can then set cookies and track the user's movement across different sites that use them. So that's usually why you get the script versions pushed in your face when you visit their respective documentation - whereas the possibilities without 3rd-party scripts and less privacy infringement are usually a bit more hidden ;-)

Comment: @CBroe Makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!